# Load a RTF with an image in it to a JTextPane

Tags: java, rtf, jtextpane

I want to load a RTF file with an image and text in it to a JTextPane.
The problem is that only the text gets sent not the image.

Heres what I tried :

```
    private static final RTFEditorKit RTF_KIT = new RTFEditorKit();
    (...)
    text.setContentType("text/rtf");
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    DefaultStyledDocument styledDocument = new DefaultStyledDocument(new StyleContext());
    RTF_KIT.read(inputStream, styledDocument, 0);
    text.setDocument(styledDocument);
```

Yes I know there are other similar questions , I didnt find an answer in any of them , thanks .

Comment: Try setting the rtfeditorkit to the JTextPane with setEditorKit, and then use getDocument instead of creating a styledDocument.

Comment: Try an alternative  http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

Comment: Thanks guys , I will try the advanced one.